# Can I check the first element only

Tags: javascript, element

Currently, the code checks for all the element whether it is = a. How can I check the first element only or the third element only?

```
    let dogName = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    
    for (i=0; i<dogName.length;i++){
        if(dogName[i] === 'a'){
            console.log('true');
    } else {
        console.log('false');
    }
}
```

Comment: `dogName[0] === 'a'`?

Comment: for (i=0; i<dogName.length;i+2) ?? -- Increment with i+2 as it skips elements

Comment: First element ```a[0]``` last element ```a[a.length -1]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the table index start as 0, you can see here all information about table in JS : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

```js
    let dogName = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    if(dogName[0] ==='a')//the first
    {


    }
    if(dogName[2]==='a')//the third
    {

    }
```